# Angular ng-repeat, ng-mouseenter, ng-mouseleave

Tags: angularjs

So I've got this repeated element...

```
<div ng-repeat="folder in user.mediaFolders | orderBy:'id'" class="pull-left media-folder">
    <div class="folder-name">{{folder.name}}</div>
    <div class="folder-body">
        <i class="fa fa-picture-o text-muted"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="popunder">
        <div class="popunder-caret"></div>
        <div class="popunder-body">
            <i class="fa fa-trash-o pull-left"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload pull-right"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The nested div with the popunder class should show when mouseover and hide with mouseout.  I would write this in jQuery as so...

```
$('.media-folder').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).find('.popunder').show();
        return false;
    },
    function(){
        $(this).find('.popunder').fadeOut('fast');
        return false;
    }
);
```

How would I do this the Angular way?

Comment: have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it all in the view using `ng-show`, `ng-mouseenter` and `ng-mouseleave` directives.

```
<div ng-repeat="folder in user.mediaFolders | orderBy:'id'" class="pull-left media-folder" ng-mouseenter="showDiv=!showDiv" ng-mouseleave="showDiv=!showDiv" ng-init="showDiv=false">
   <div class="folder-name">{{folder.name}}</div>
   <div class="folder-body">
       <i class="fa fa-picture-o text-muted"></i>
   </div>
   <div class="popunder" ng-show="showDiv">
       <div class="popunder-caret"></div>
       <div class="popunder-body">
           <i class="fa fa-trash-o pull-left"></i>
           <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload pull-right"></i>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

You can then use `ngAnimate` if you like some animation. Of course, there are other ways of achieving same.

Comment: Just to add to this, you will use ngAnimate for the fade out or any other animation behaviors.

Comment: I saw the edit come through immediately after I typed the comment :)

Comment: Brilliant.  Thank you.  I'm only a few weeks into Angular and it's weird but I love it.

Comment: @Tim, Angular creates an isolated scope for each of the `folder` items.

Comment: @ranru, you are correct, deleting my comment so nobody is misled by it.